# Unable to remove the characters using regex

Tags: regex, perl

This is my string:

> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
>   "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ull

I want to remove all letter 'x' and '♥'

Heres my code:

```
((>|<|q)?[=:8;]{1}(')?(-)?[><\)\(\/cdopsx:^*]|\([\w\s]+\)|([:P$])|([|-])|(&#9829;{0,}.)|(x{0,}.))
```

but it is not working, can anyone help me...when i am using in perl regex

```
$string =~ s/((>|<|q)?[=:8;]{1}(')?(-)?[><\)\(\/cdopsx:^*]|\([\w\s]+\)|([:P$])|([|-])|(&#9829;{0,}.)|(x{0,}.))//g;
```

Comment: so you want your resulting string to end with "`quis nostrud eercitation ull`" (i.e. the "`x`" in the third-to-last-word is removed as well)?

Comment: no, just fromn the top letters before "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, to be removed.

Comment: I don't know the exact requirements, but wouldn't it be easier to just use `[^\w\s,." ]+|([^\W\d_])\1{3,}` ? You edit the first part to remove the other characters you want to allow. The second part will match 4 consecutive same letters. [Check this demo out](http://regex101.com/r/vC6mI8)

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking", because your question doesn't say what your requirements are. (Unless your requirement really is just to remove all instances of `x` and `♥`, in which case the regex you posted seems like it must be a joke.)

Comment: @ruakh, this is the common strings which users type in the greeting card, 'x' and ♥, therefore we are having problem in printing, we are find a solution to remove those letters before printing.

Comment: @jazzrai: Well, I'm not sure that business requirement makes sense -- if your users want to include those characters, then it seems like it's your job to print them -- but O.K., let's set that aside for now. What I don't get is -- where on Earth did your regex come from? Because most of it has nothing to do with removing those characters.

Comment: Why not split long strings into chunks? If the problem is that it's breaking your HTML layout, then you can solve the problem with a bit of CSS: `word-wrap:break-word`. Can't help feeling that just removing long lines is the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just remove everything before first double quote:

```
s/^[^"]+//
```